# How to check if a value is None and save to another variable only if it is not None in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following piece of code works fine.

```
a = 2.0
b = int(a)
```

And `b` is `2`.

But the following does not work:

```
a = None
b = int(a)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

This works:

```
a = None
if a != None:
    b = int(a)
else:
    b = 0
```

But it is too much code because I have several such variables in my use case that can be None.

What I want:

- b = a, if a is not None.
- b = 0, if a is None

Is there an elegant way of doing this with a built in function or something that I am not aware of the existence of...?

Comment: does a one-liner suit your needs? Like `b = int(a) if a != None else 0`

Comment: Not desirable but it will be the case if I cannot figure out a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a short way: `b = int(a or 0)`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to try this a bunch of times, you could make a very small function with a `try:...except:...` block.

```py
def try_int(v):
    try:
        return int(v)
    except TypeError:
        return 0

a = 2
b = try_int(a) # should return 2
c = None
d = try_int(c) # should return 0
```

This solution sticks to the principal of 'asking for forgiveness, not permission' and also not repeating yourself by having a bunch of separate `try:...except:...` blocks and instead just the one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is equally good as the accepted one, in my opinion.